# maxmin clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I read a a paper that mention max min clustering algorithm, but i don't really quite understand what this algorithm does. Googling "max min clustering algorithm" doesn't yield any helpful result. does anybody know what this algorithm mean? this is an excerpt of the paper:

Max-min clustering proceeds by choosing an observation at random as the first centroid c1, and by setting the set C of centroids to {c1}. ***During the ith iteration, ci is chosen such that it maximizes the minimum Euclidean distance between ci and observations in C***. Max-min clustering is preferable to a density-based clustering algorithm (e.g. k-means) which would tend to select many examples from the dense group of non-seizure data points.

I don't quite understand the bolded part. 
link to paper is [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjmlr.org%2Fproceedings%2Fpapers%2Fv22%2Fbalakrishnan12b%2Fbalakrishnan12b.pdf&ei=sDc4VLCyKMP6PKi6gYAG&usg=AFQjCNHDbdqrJ5JjFj5XC6AUr6Yv7Q9W1A&sig2=2WDDZga4voky3xNtN58WCQ&bvm=bv.77161500,d.ZWU)

Comment: Can you please link the paper here?

Comment: updated in the question section

Comment: Do you have an updated link to the paper? i think i can help but the link is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

We choose each new centroid to be as far as possible from the existing centroids. Here's some Python code.

```
def maxminclustering(observations, k):
    observations = set(observations)
    if k < 1 or not observations: return set()
    centroids = set([observations.pop()])
    for i in range(min(k - 1, len(observations))):
        newcentroid = max(observations,
                          key=lambda observation:
                                  min(distance(observation, centroid)
                                      for centroid in centroids))
        observations.remove(newcentroid)
        centroids.add(newcentroid)
    return centroids
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the farthest-points heuristic for *seeding* k-means, but then not performing any k-means iterations at all.

This is a surprisingly simple, but quite effective strategy. Basically it will find a number of data points that are well spread out, which can make k-means converge fast. Usually, one would discard the first (random) data point.

It only works well for low values of k though (it avoids placing centroids in the center of the data set!), and it is not very favorable to multiple runs - it tends to choose the same initial centroids again.

K-means++ can be seen as a more randomized version of this. Instead of always choosing the farthes object, it chooses far objects with increased likelihood, but may at random also choose a near neighbor. This way, you get more diverse results when running it multiple times.

You can try it out in ELKI, it is named `FarthestPointsInitialMeans`. If you choose the algorithm `SingleAssignmentKMeans`, then it will not perform k-means iterations, but only do the initial assignment. That will probably give you this "MaxMin clustering" algorithm.